# How to append a new label in all GCP Cloud Logging Logs generated by different Vertex AI pipeline components

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to build a Vertex AI pipeline for Model Serving and it will have different components such as - Dataflow(pre-processing) , Vertex AI Batch Prediction operator , Dataproc(Postprocessing) , Python components .
The pipeline will have unique run_id that I want to add as a custom label in all cloud logging entries generated by pipeline components.

1. Is there any way we can append custom metadata to all log entries (generated by the service + the custom log messages generated by the app ) .
2. For Custom Log messages , if I do something like this in my application code running on GCE then I am able to see the custom label in the Cloud Logging -

```
import logging
import google.cloud.logging
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from vertex_logger.lib import test_module


def log_handler(run_id):
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
    handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client,labels={'run_id' : f'{run_id}'})

    cloud_logger = logging.getLogger()
    cloud_logger.root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    cloud_logger.root.addHandler(handler)

    return cloud_logger


if __name__=='__main__':
    logger=log_handler('BATCH_TEST_1')
    logger.info('this is a new test')
    test_module.write_log('from within the module')
```

However when I am following the same approach for one of the Dataflow jobs , then those custom labels are not getting added .

```
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from google.cloud import logging as cloud_logging
from google.cloud.logging_v2.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler

batch_id = 'Custom_batch_id_20230713'

client = cloud_logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client,labels={'run_id' : f'{batch_id}'})
logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(handler)

input_file = 'gs://xxx/test_dataflow_source.txt'
output_path = 'gs://xxx/output/counts.txt'
beam_options = PipelineOptions(
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    project='xxx',
    job_name='xxx',
    temp_location='gs://xxx/temp/',
)

def write_log(element):
    logging.info(f"processing element {element}")

pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options)

pipeline \
   | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file) \
   | 'ExtractWords' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: re.findall(r'[A-Za-z\']+', x)) \
   | beam.combiners.Count.PerElement() \
   | beam.MapTuple(lambda word, count: '%s: %s' % (word, count)) \
   | beam.Map(write_log) \
   | beam.io.WriteToText(output_path) 

result = pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

I have tried using the below code but that is also not helping -

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.root.addHandler(handler)
```

When I am checking the log entries , it is using a logger - /tmp/tmpe7cn9w4e/test_dataflow.py:28
unlike the case in GCE , where the logger is -

```
labels: {
run_id: "BATCH_TEST_1"
python_logger: "root"
}
textPayload: "this is a new test"
```

So it seems like , dataflow workers are not using the 'root' logger and that is why my custtom handler is not being picked up .

I even tried to add the extra key-values , but that does not work either -

```
def write_log(element):
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(format="%(test)s - %(message)s")
    logging.info(f"processing element {element}",extra={'test':'batch'})
```

Logs in Cloud Logging -

```
{
insertId: "3596541986852404902:155282:0:14565"
jsonPayload: {
instruction: "process_bundle-7611360226246467578-7"
work: "7611360226246467578"
worker: "dataflow-preprocess-dummy-07132025-nbtw-harness-4rpr"
thread: "Thread-16"
logger: "/tmp/tmps9t8aye5/test_dataflow.py:30"
step: "Map(write_log)"
portability_worker_id: "sdk-0-0"
message: "processing element check: 1"
job: "2023-07-13_20_25_26-13322174957478015553"
}
```

Comment: I do not think the worker log can be configured to achieve what you want. I have two suggestions to achieve this: 1) you could use encode `run_id` as the Dataflow `job_name` or 2) your could use `labels` for your Dataflow job.